# sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors - knn for unsupervised learning?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-nn

From basic theory I know that knn is a supervised algorithm while for example k-means is an unsupervised algorithm.

However, at Sklearn there are is an implementation of KNN for unsupervised learning (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors).

What is exactly this unsupervised version of knn at SkLearn?

Is this a knn algorithm?

- If yes how it is unsupervised since by definition knn is supervised?
- If no what is it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unsupervised version simply implements different algorithms to find the nearest neighbor(s) for each sample.

The kNN algorithm consists of two steps:

1. Compute and store the k nearest neighbors for each sample in the training set ("training")
2. For an unlabeled sample, retrieve the k nearest neighbors from dataset and predict label through majority vote / interpolation (or similar) among k nearest neighbors ("prediction/querying")

The unsupervised version is basically only step 1, the training phase of the kNN algorithm.

(This is useful because if your dataset is large, a pairwise comparison for all samples (`algorithm='brute'`) is often infeasible. Therefore two alternative algorithms for the training stage are implemented that make use of previous comparisons to reduce the number of distance calculations. See the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#unsupervised-nearest-neighbors).)

Comment: Thanksfor the answer @oW (upvote). "The unsupervised version simply implements different algorithms to find the nearest neighbor(s) for each sample.", by different you mean different than knn or different the one to each other? Also, my main question is: is this a knn algorithm? If yes how it is unsupervised since by definition knn is supervised? If no what is it then?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! Then how diffirent is this unsupervised version of knn to kmeans which is essentialy again about neighbors in an unsupervised way? (I am going to look it up in more detail but if you can come up effortlessly with a concise answer then it is even better)

Comment: kMeans is for clustering, the unsupervised kNN is just that... a way to find nearest neighbors in a dataset... what you do with that calculation is up to you.

Comment: Ok, perhaps I am missing something. But essentially clustering (in kmeans) is done exactly by identifying "neighbors" (at least to a centroid which may be or may not be an actual data) for each cluster. What is its difference then to unsupervised knn? Is it that the unsupervised knn is identifying neighbors between the actual data points whereas kmeans is identifying neighbors to centroids (which may not be actual data points)?

Comment: also k in kMeans refers to the number of clusters not the number of neighbors. in kMeans you only need to compute the distance from the data points to the centroid not to other data points. you don't really care about "neighbors"

Comment: Yes, that's right. Even though clusters are formed exactly because of neighbors to a centroidso in this sense it seems that there is some overlapping between unsupervised knn and k-means. But yes at the end what you say it is true.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion comes from the way Sklearn designed their code.

## Short answer

The "unsupervised" version you mention is not a K-Nearest Neighbour algorithm (which is implemented [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier)). In its description, it only reads:

> "Unsupervised learner for implementing neighbour searches."

This learner is actually used by `KNNClassifier` in order to perform neighbour searches efficiently. Sklearn made it as a separate learner because other algorithms such as `KMeans` also need to perform neighbour searches.

## Long answer

There exist many algorithms which require neighbour searches. KNN and K-Means being some of the famous ones. As a design choice, Sklearn decided to implement the neighbour search part as its own "learner".

To find a nearest-neighbour, you can obviously compute all pairwise distances but it might not be very efficient. This is why there exist smarter ways which use specific data structures like a KD-Tree or a Ball-Tree (Ball trees typically perform better than KD-Trees on high dimensional data by the way).

If you `fit` the unsupervised `NearestNeighbors` model, you will store the data in a data structure based on the value you set for the `algorithm` argument. And you can then use this unsupervised learner's `kneighbors` in a model which require neighbour searches.